# Inject variable inside Config

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this config

```
angular.module('moduleApp.config')
.config(['$translateProvider', '$languageSupportProvider',
         function($translateProvider, $languageSupportProvider) {
   // I need to access myService.getLocale();
}]);
```

My service

```
angular.module("moduleApp.services")
.service("moduleApp.MyService", MyService);

MyService.$inject = [];

function MyService() {

    this.getLocale = function() {
        // etc
       return "en";
    };
}
```

If I try to add the service in the config I get an error. How can I get the service data inside the config?

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module("moduleApp")
.service("MyService", MyService);

function MyService() {

    this.getLocale = function() {
        // etc
       return "en";
    };
}
```

````
.config(['$translateProvider', '$languageSupportProvider', 'MyService'
         function($translateProvider, $languageSupportProvider, MyService) {
   var locale = MyService.getLocale();
}]);```
````